# Export a TypeScript class from another file than it has been defined in

Tags: typescript, module

For a while I've been trying to export the classes from a little library I wrote in a single place. I want each class do be agnostic of how they are made available to the outside but I can't get that to work so far.

Let's assume I've got the class `Foo`

```js
// lib/foo.ts
export class Foo {}
```

and the class `Bar`

```js
// lib/bar.ts
export class Bar {}
```

Now I want to make those available to whoever uses the package via the `MyModule` namespace and this is where it gets tricky. I don't know how to export existing classes from a namespace defined in another place than the class itself.

Obviously, this won't work because it's not valid TypeScript:

```js
// api.ts
import { Foo } from "./lib/foo";
import { Bar } from "./lib/bar";

export namespace MyModule {
    export Foo;

    export namespace MySubModule {
        export Bar;
    }
}
```

I have found two potential solutions to this, but both do have their downsides. I can define a variable and assign the class to it:

```js
// api.ts
import { Foo as MyFoo } from "./lib/foo";
import { Bar as MyBar } from "./lib/bar";

export namespace MyModule {
    export const Foo = MyFoo;

    export namespace MySubModule {
        export const Bar = MyBar;
    }
}
```

This will in fact allow me to create instances of the class from an external place like `new MyModule.MySubModule.Bar` but won't give me the possibility to use them as types since

```js
let myBarInstance: MyModule.MySubModule.Bar;
```

will throw a TypeScript error stating that

> Module "path/to/module/api".MySubModule has no exported member 'Bar'

The other way around I tried to use `export type Bar = MyBar` instead of `const` and while this works when saying

```js
let myBarInstance: MyModule.MySubModule.Bar
```

on the other hand I naturally cannot instantiate `MyModule.MySubModule.Bar` since it's just a type alias.

All of this goes the same way for the `Foo` class.

Does anyone have any experience with this, have I maybe overlooked some other exporting feature TypeScript is providing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So Ryan Cavanaugh from the TypeScript team was kind enough [to answer my question](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10058#issuecomment-236458961) over at their GitHub.

It's actually pretty easy: Just combine both of the approaches I came up with and you're good to go:

```js
// api.ts
import { Foo as MyFoo } from "./lib/foo";
import { Bar as MyBar } from "./lib/bar";

export namespace MyModule {
    export const Foo = MyFoo;
    export type Foo = MyFoo;

    export namespace MySubModule {
        export const Bar = MyBar;
        export type Bar = MyBar;
    }
}
```

---

> **EDIT 2020:** Now that I have some more years of TypeScript experience, I think I should provide an additional explanation *why* the code above works. This may be valuable information for new-ish TypeScript developers, because it touches a topic that is not often taught: TypeScript's separate type scope.

TypeScript basically maintains a type scope parallel to the variable scope of JavaScript. This means that you may define a variable `foo` and a type `foo` in the same file. They don't even need to be compatible:

```js
const foo = 'bar'
type foo = number
```

Now classes in TypeScript are a little bit special. What happens if you define a class `Foo` is that TypeScript not only creates a variable `Foo` (containing the class object itself) it *also declares a type `Foo`*, representing an instance of that class.

Similarly, when importing a name from another file, both — any defined *variable and type* under that name — are imported. This means that in the code above, `MyFoo` holds the `Foo` class object as well as the `Foo` class type from `foo.ts`.

So if we re-export `MyFoo` from inside the `MyModule` namespace by writing `export const Foo = MyFoo`, only the class *object* is exported (because a `const` only ever holds a value, not a type). Similarly, if we'd do `export type Foo = MyFoo`, only the class *type* would be exported.

So now we've come full circle: Because of the independent scopes, it's valid to export a value and a type under the same name. And in some cases (like this one), it's not only valid but necessary.